# Is there a Microsoft technology equivalent of DAOS?

Tags: ibm-domino, lotus-notes

**DAOS** = Domino Attachment and Object Store, a neat technology we have been using for the last decade or so primarily in a huge document and email database. DAOS effectively de-duplicates attachments and objects over a certain size by replacing them with links to an object store (e.g. so instead of storing 23 identical copies of a 10Mb file attachment it stores 1 plus 23 links).  It has saved us humungous amounts of disk space.

Now we need to migrate our stuff to a Microsoft platform and they don't seem to have anything similar.... or do they?

Comment: **Now we need to migrate our stuff to a Microsoft platform** - What does that exactly mean?

Comment: Sharepoint or SQL Server are favourites. The idea is close down Domino in due course.